# TFS 2015 Update 2 Build Failed

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, tfs-2015

We're running TFS 2015 update 2. When a build starts,  it says "Waiting for an agent" then, 2 seconds after,  the build fails.  I looked whether the agent pools were running, and all of them were on green (as I understand this is expected).  Also,  I looked whether the TFSJobsAgent was running,  and it's ok.  If I download the zip log from de build process,  it is empty,  so i don't know what i'm doing wrong.  i tried to create a new agent pool,  and run the build process on that agent,  but i got the same result.

Any ideas on how to tackle/solve this?

PS: All the builds were working fine a week ago.

Answer (score 0):

The build service account needs to be a member of the Build Service Accounts group.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to check whether the build agent service is running.